# Detect DOM level in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

There are multiple levels of DOM. Is there a DOM API for JavaScript which could detect the highest supported DOM level of current execution engine at runtime?

Comment: Don't test for levels of DOM -- test for the feature you need. What do you need to use?

Comment: @lonesomeday test specific feature would work. I'd like to see whether DOM level could be tested to reduce the number concrete feature tests.

Comment: Seems useless, as implementations will often cover a bit more or less (or both) compared to a DOM level requirement. But just test a feature that is new in a certain DOM level.

Comment: The number of features you must test is the number of features your application needs. There's no point in trying to determine an imaginary DOM level.

Comment: @Thomson To be blunt, that would be a stupid idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. There used to be but it has been removed.

Introduced in DOM 1, [document.implementation.hasFeature( "HTML", "1.0")](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-5CED94D7) was supposed to return true if HTML was supported at DOM level 1.0. Whilst a presumption might be made that this could be used to detect the DOM level supported by increasing the version parameter until false is returned, implementations of the feature were unreliable to the point that [DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-dom-20151119/#dom-domimplementation-hasfeature) requires the method to return true in all cases so as not to break the web.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature) warns not to use `hasFeature` and to remove it from existing code if possible

That leaves standard feature detection by means of either checking for the presence and type of DOM methods that need to be used or trying them inside `try/catch` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(document.implementation){
        if(document.implementation.hasFeature('Core','2.0')){
            alert('DOM2 Core supported');
        }else{
            alert('DOM2 Core not supported');
        }

    }
```

Comment: Reference the Chapter 3 in the book <<AdvancED DOM Scripting Dynamic Web Design Techniques>> and see the details and usage